# Store selenium request in jmeter to use in the next request

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am trying to use the login from selenium to use in the next http request in jmeter. I currently have the below

[image]

My selenium script works perfectly and logs me into my website as per the below

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://www.testwebsite.com')
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText("Login")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("username")).sendKeys("myusername");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("password")).sendKeys("mypassword");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Skip for now')]")).click();
var cookies = WDS.browser.manage().getCookies()
java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

What i want to do is keep this session alive and then on the next request use something like this

GET - https://test/anotherpage.com

so i want it to recognise im still logged in. How can i keep the session alive so my jmeter http request can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your WebDriver Sampler you need to store the `cookies` object into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   WDS.vars.putObject('cookies', cookies)
   ```
2. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler where you need to get the authentication context and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def cookies = vars.getObject('cookies')
   log.info('cookies=' + cookies)
   cookies.collect { cookie ->
       new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie(cookie.getName(),
               cookie.getValue(),
               cookie.getDomain(),
               cookie.getPath(),
               cookie.isSecure(),
               cookie.getExpiry().getTime())
   }.each { cookie -> sampler.getCookieManager().add(cookie) }
   ```

This way you can copy the cookies from the browser to HTTP Request sampler so the request will be authenticated

More information: [Modifying Cookies in JMeter with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modifying-cookies-in-jmeter-with-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, where should i put the cookie code block in the webdriver sampler as i added it to the end and im getting an error of '"cookies" is not defined in <eval> at line number 9'

Comment: Ive amended it and i dont get an error any more but i cant see any cookies being stored as the other request on another thread is not pulling the cookie through and just says no cookies Even if its in the same thread i get the same result. I can see the cookie in the debug sampler as part of the chrome response so im unsure why its not storing it

Comment: I can see the erro now, its saying
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script38.groovy: 9: expecting ')', found '}' @ line 9, column 1.
   }.each { cookie -> sampler.getCookieManager().add(cookie) }
   ^

Comment: The script doesnt work for the jsr223 but i have been able to pull the cookies through from the webdriver so ill accept the answer and raise another question

Answer (score 0):

Using cookies in selenium, which it looks like yuou've fetched all of them:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/

YHou should be able to store those cookies, which should be enough to preserve your session.
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter

> To save cookies as variables, define the property
> "CookieManager.save.cookies=true".  The names of the cookies contain
> the prefix "COOKIE_" before they are stored (this avoids accidental
> corruption of local variables). To revert to the original behavior,
> define the property "CookieManager.name.prefix= " (with one or more
> spaces). If enabled, the value of a cookie with the name TEST can be
> referred to as ${COOKIE_TEST}.

That being said, you probably don't need to use selenium (and launch a full browser) to do the login, you could probably fire a simple http request to post the login form. This would be less over head
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication

Comment: Hi Dmart, i cant do this via a standard http request as the website does not allow POST requests via jmeter so i have to use selenium. Ill have a look at that link further as webdriver request doesnt seem to be storing the cookie in the request

Comment: I believe you need to then STORE the cookies as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I cant seem to store the cookie. In the request i can see com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler@3d602040 and it doesnt show anything else. If i try to use a variable for cookies nothing happens. Its like it cant pick up the cookie from the browser and bring back into jmeter